# Plugin architecture in Spring web application

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm designing Spring web application (I use Spring MVC) follow plugin architecture. Each plugin (plugin is a jar file) with its components (Controller, Service, POJO,..) will be contained in each ApplicationContext, whenever I disable that plugin (by closing its ApplicationContext) then user will receive an message say that "The feature or function is not available". When I refresh again plugin's ApplicationContext that plugin will be available again and user can access the feature of that plugin. Plugins don't depend with each other, it just depends on the Core module. But in Spring only child context can see the parent context not vice-versa. Because of this limitation of Spring I have some other ideas to implement it as below:

1/ I create an annotation @Plugin to mark on package of that plugin and using AOP to intercept user access. Whenever plugin is disabled then user cannot access that plugin's service/controller and an exception will raise to notify to user on web page.

2/ Not support disable plugin at runtime. Server needs to stop and we have to remove that jar file to uninstall that plugin from web application

3/ Create a channing ApplicationContext that will lookup beans or components in many ApplicationContext and using this one for DispatcherServlet.

Could anyone give me some advices about this? Which above idea should I use or none of them? I want to develop a web application that we can install/uninstall plugin at runtime without restart the server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try to use spring osgi with gemini? http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/documentation/reference/1.0.2.RELEASE/html/app-deploy.html